# Solving partial fraction expansion with all variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

Okay so I have an equation in my book which is as follows..
$$
\frac {a}{s(s+a)}
$$
it says "using partial fractions this can be expanded to
$$
\frac {1}{s} + \frac {-1}{s+a}
$$

My usual method would be to cross multiply and do something like this 
$$
\frac {a}{s(s+a)} = \frac {A(s+a)}{s(s+a)} + \frac {B(s)}{s(s+a)}
$$

Then cancel off the denominators and solve..

$$
a = A(s+a) + B(s)
$$

usually though the a would be some constant but here I have no values to play around with.. how has he done it in the book?

Comment: Sometimes you have $s+a$ in the denominator; sometimes $s+1$.  Which is correct?

Comment: Sorry I copied it down wrongly.. I have redone it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$\dfrac{a}{s(s+a)} = \dfrac{A}{s}+\dfrac{B}{s+a}$$

So,

$$a = A(s+a) + Bs = (A+B)s + A a$$

we have $A = 1, B = -1$

Final result:

$$\dfrac{a}{s(s+1)} = \dfrac{1}{s}-\dfrac{1}{s+a}$$

Comment: Ahh right I get it.. Making A+B = 0 and making A = 1.. Leaves us with a = 0 + 1*a, which means a=a.. Thanks!

Comment: You got it, but I look at it slightly different. We see the LHS is $a$ by itself, right off that tells us what $Aa$ is, so $A = 1$. Now I need for the $(A+B)s$ to cancel, and already know $A$, so $B = -1$. Clear? Regards

Answer (score 1):

The equality you have is 
$$
a=(A-B)s+aA.
$$
This suggests taking $A=B=1$.

Comment: Sorry i totally copied it down wrong.. I have changed it now

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=0$, so $a=Aa$.  Let $s=1$, so $a=A(a+1)+B$
Solve for $A$ and $B$.